# SPARK STREAMING: I want to do some streaming exercises, how to get a good stream data source?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I want to do some streaming exercises, how to get a good stream data source ?
I am looking for both structure streaming data source and non structured streaming data source. 
Will twitter work?

Answer (score 0):

Local files can be used as sources in structured streaming, e.g.:

```py
stream = spark.readStream.schema(mySchema).option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).json("/my/data")
```

With this you can experiment on data transformation and output very easily, and there are many sample datasets online, e.g. on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets)

If you want to have something production-like, twitter api is a good option. You will need some sort of a messaging middleware though, like Kafka or Azure Event Hub - a simple app can send tweets there and you will be able to pick them up easily from Spark. You can also generate data yourself on the input side instead of depending on Twitter.